# Strange symbols in log with winston

Tags: node.js, winston

Initialization:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    levels: {
        trace: 0,
        input: 1,
        verbose: 2,
        prompt: 3,
        debug: 4,
        info: 5,
        data: 6,
        help: 7,
        warn: 8,
        error: 9
    },
    colors: {
        trace: 'magenta',
        input: 'grey',
        verbose: 'cyan',
        prompt: 'grey',
        debug: 'blue',
        info: 'green',
        data: 'grey',
        help: 'cyan',
        warn: 'yellow',
        error: 'red'
    }
});

logger.add(winston.transports.Console, {
    level: 'error',
    prettyPrint: true,
    colorize: true,
    silent: false,
    timestamp: false,
    json: false
});
```

For example I call logger like this:

```
logger.info("isSandBox: " + isSandBox);
```

In my IDEA I see:

> info: isSandBox: true

But when I've uploaded this script to Ubuntu server, I saw in the log:

> ^[[32minfo^[[39m: isSandBox: true

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you logging the console output to a file on your Ubuntu server? Those strange symbols are the color code escapes, and they are meant for a console logger. If you want to log to a file, use a file transport, or disable `colorize`.

Comment: @robertklep supervisord logs it into the file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The codes you're seeing are color code escapes. They are only useful when logging to a terminal/console, as they get interpreted by the terminal to change the text color. If the logs end up in a file, the codes are stored as-is, and are not really useful.

You can check if the output if a terminal, and only enable colorisation when it is:

```
logger.add(winston.transports.Console, {
    level       : 'error',
    prettyPrint : true,
    colorize    : process.stdout.isTTY,
    silent      : false,
    timestamp   : false,
    json        : false
});
```

More info on the `isTTY` flag [here](https://nodejs.org/api/tty.html#tty_tty).

Comment: With `colorize: process.stdout.isTTY` there is no colors neither in IDEA, nor in the file.

Comment: IDEA is probably not a proper terminal either, although it may support color codes nonetheless. In that case, you need to find a way to determine if the app was started in IDEA or not, but I have no experience with it so no idea if that's possible.

Answer (score 4):

In case you weren't able to solve this.. I was able to just now.

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, label, colorize, printf } = format;

const myFormat = printf(info => {
  return `${info.timestamp} ${info.label} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
});

const logger = createLogger({
  format: combine(
    colorize(),
    label({ label: '[app-server]' }),
    timestamp(),
    myFormat
  ),
  transports: [new transports.Console()]
});

module.exports = logger;
```

The myFormat var is what allows it. None of the out of box formatters have the ability to translate the color code escapes.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting the format colorize inside the transport creation

```
const transports = [
  new winston.transports.Console({
    format: winston.format.colorize({ all: true }),
  }),
  new winston.transports.File({
    filename: 'logs/error.log',
    level: 'error',
  }),
  new winston.transports.File({
    filename: 'logs/all.log',
  }),
];
```

After defining each one of the parameters of "createLogger" i call

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level,
  levels,
  format,
  transports,
});
```

This way my console transport prints in color, and i don't get the unescaped characters in my file logs.